# Add each preceeding value of a list to the next

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm trying to add each element of a list, starting at position 1, with the preceeding value, ie:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 7, 3, 10]
```

Would be calculating:

```
mylist = [1, 2+1, 7+3, 3+10, 10+13]
```

To get:

```
mylist = [1, 3, 10, 13, 23]
```

I can get the result I want with the following code:

```
counter, counter1 = 0, 1
for n in mylist[1:]:
    mylist[counter1] = mylist[counter1] + mylist[counter]
    counter += 1
    counter1 += 1
```

Five lines of code seems like too many for what seems to me to be a pretty simple problem. Anyone got a sleeker solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single list comprehension, just add the current item to the sum of the slice of all preceding items:

```
mylist = [item + sum(mylist[:index]) for index, item in enumerate(mylist)]
```

Comment: `[sum(mylist[:i+1]) for i,_ in enumerate(mylist)]` easier?

Comment: @ssm slightly shorter, but otherwise does much the same! Not sure if putting everything into `sum` would be more efficient or not.

Comment: Or for that matter, since we are not using the values in the iteration, `[sum(mylist[:i]) for i in range(1, len(mylist)+1)]`

Comment: That one I would put the +1 in the slice to shorten the `range`, but otherwise yes.

Comment: I always wished I could use the last value of the list being created for situations like this. Ever felt the same way? I hate it when I cant do that. The last value is there in memory somewhee. I just cant get it.

Comment: Thanks guys - all these worked a treat. I'm still getting my head around list comprehensions - I've just touched on them briefly so far.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a cumulative sum. In `numpy` there is a function `numpy.cumsum` which you can use directly. That is perhaps the most efficient.

Alternatively, what you need is a counter which adds elements as you traverse through the list:

```
newList = []
counter = 0
for n in mylist: 
    counter += n
    newList.append(counter)
```

This is the more pythonic way of doing it. Although, you can replace elements on-the-go:

```
for i, n in enumerate(mylist[1:]):
     mylist[i+1] = mylist[i] + n
```

In-place updating of lists elements within loops are generally never a good idea, so I would discourage you from doing this.

You can use `reduce`. This is a functional approach. This will need you to think critically about your algorithm. This uses lambda functions, and is generally scoffed-at by Python programmers, because, it is not always very readable to most people (although I find it ok and use it for my own programs).

```
In [356]: reduce( lambda x, y: x + [x[-1] + y], mylist, [0])[1:]
Out[356]: [1, 3, 10, 13, 23]
```

Remember that in this case, you will need to pass an initial value which is what is done above. Alternately, you can try:

```
In [357]: reduce( lambda x, y: x + [x[-1] + y], mylist[1:], mylist[:1])
Out[357]: [1, 3, 10, 13, 23]
```

Which comes to the same thing and is a little cleaner ...

Finally you can use list comprehensions. This is already shown, but for the slicing used, I dont know if it is a significant improvement over the `reduce`.

Comment: Thank you too, also works, but alas, lambda means more to me in the Half-Life context than the Python at this stage of my journey. :-)